# how to replace doubleslash in form app in c#

Tags: c#, forms

I have an app i am trying to  replace double slash with single slash i have my code as shown

```
string path = C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\filename
path = path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

The above code is not working and is giving me "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\filename"

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio adds an extra escape ` \ ` . There is actually no extra ` \ ` in your string.

Comment: try using this : ``string path = @ "C:\Users\test\Desktop\filename"``